# custom tableview and highlightedTextColor

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

i have a table view, with custom cell, i have set the cell for have a highlighted color on text when you tap on it.

//cell specific

```
NSString *ligneTableau = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[table objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] nome]];
cell.label.text = ligneTableau;  
cell.label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"populaire" size:35];
cell.label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:124.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue:106.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
cell.fondo.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"cell_ant.png"];    

//highlighted Text

cell.label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:55.0f/255.0f green:70.0f/255.0f blue:48.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

every things work fine, but when come back to the table the text stay highlighted.

I forget somethings?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cell remains selected when you go back to table. So as soon as come back to table you should set deselected.

```
    [cell setSelected:NO];
```

Comment: try in  -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated

Comment: nope, bur think the problem is another, here were i declare and set my custom cell.

     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {    
    //fondo tabella trasparente
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UpdatesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        
     
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UpdatesTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

Answer (score 0):

In your `UpdatesTableViewCell` class, you can implement the following methods:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    if (highlighted)
        self.label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:55.0f/255.0f green:70.0f/255.0f blue:48.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    else
        self.label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:124.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue:106.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if (selected)
        self.label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:55.0f/255.0f green:70.0f/255.0f blue:48.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    else
        self.label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:124.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue:106.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: it's a good idea but there is a problem, updatesTableviewcell is a class used by more that one controller and every tame change the colors of label.

Comment: You're creating a new instance of that class for each re-usable cell, it doesn't matter if you're using it in more than one view controller. Have you tried the code above? If you want it to only occur for certain view controllers then you can add another variable in `UpdatesTableViewCell` such as `whichViewController` and when populating the table put `cell.whichViewController = @"First"`. Then in your `UpdatesTableViewCell` class check for `[cell.whichViewController isEqualToString:@"First"]` inside the methods shown above.

Comment: mmmm interesting, i not very sure that i understand (i am very newbie), let's me try!!